# pass data from form to form in asp mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

let say I have 2 form in my view. Let say form A and form B
What I want is to pass value in form A to form B, then form B is send to controller.

this is form A:

```
@for (var k = 0; k < Model.feedback.Count; k++)
                    {
 <td>
   <textarea class="form-control" id="comment-@k" rows="1"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.feedback[k].Comment)</textarea>
 </td>
}
```

here is the button to pass value form A --> form B

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="savecomment" >Save Changes</button>
```

this is form B:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Feedback", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                for (var e = 0; e < Model.feedback.Count; e++)
                {               
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => Model.feedback[e].Comment, new { @id = "comment-" + e })
                }
```

Is there anyone can help how to do this? I think it need to use javascript. can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Yes, you need JavaScript to respond to client side events. But why do you have 2 forms (your UI is not really making sense)?

Comment: What's your purpose by putting `DisplayFor` inside `textarea`: `<textarea class="form-control" id="comment-@k" rows="1"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.feedback[k].Comment)</textarea>` (this doesn't makes sense at a glance)? I think you can just use single form to post entire control contents.

Comment: Form A isn't a form (with a `form` html tag). It's simply textareas in html codes... If i understand you want to map all the textareas between us ? Why not use only one form ?

Comment: so, after I input the text area in form A, and click save button, I want another form (form B) like "are you sure you want to save?" comes out. then click another save button.

Comment: That makes no sense. Just delete your first 'form' and handle the `.submit()` event of your proper form and display your message as a dialog (and cancel the submit if they click no)